# TypeScript compilation errors for Twilio Functions

Tags: typescript, twilio

Running `npx tsc` results in these errors:

```
node_modules/@twilio-labs/serverless-runtime-types/types.d.ts:5:10 - error TS2305: Module '"twilio/lib/rest/Twilio"' has no exported member 'TwilioClientOptions'.

5 import { TwilioClientOptions } from 'twilio/lib/rest/Twilio';
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@twilio-labs/serverless-runtime-types/types.d.ts:415:10 - error TS2305: Module '"twilio/lib/rest/Twilio"' has no exported member 'TwilioClientOptions'.

415 export { TwilioClientOptions } from 'twilio/lib/rest/Twilio';
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It looks like the actual TS files themselves are still being compiled successfully, but I'm not sure whether I can safely ignore this error or not, and if there is something I can do to avoid it. I don't know if the issue is some sort of dependency mismatch or what.

I'm aware I can add `skipLibCheck` to my tsconfig.json to prevent the error altogether, but I may be silencing other issues which crop up in the future.

Minimum reproducible instructions:

functions/test.ts

```
import { ServerlessFunctionSignature } from '@twilio-labs/serverless-runtime-types/types';

export const handler: ServerlessFunctionSignature = async function(
  context,
  event,
  callback
) {
  callback(null, true);
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./compiled",
    "rootDir": "./functions",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "types": ["@twilio-labs/serverless-runtime-types/index.d.ts"],
  } 
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@twilio-labs/serverless-runtime-types": "^3.0.0",
    "twilio": "^4.23.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  }
}
```

To clarify, there is no issue with type hinting or completion or anything like that. The only issue is when trying to compile.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use the types in TypeScript to get autocomplete in VS Code and other editors using the TypeScript language server:

**Option 1: Modify your tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["node_modules/@twilio-labs/serverless-runtime-types/index.d.ts"]
  }
}
```

**Option 2: Import the file**

```
import "@twilio-labs/serverless-runtime-types";

export function handler(context, event, callback) {
  let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();
  twiml.message("Hello World");
  callback(null, twiml);
}
```

Comment: This is not my issue. And if you see the tsconfig.json file I provided, I already have that option set.

Comment: I see can you add node_modules in front of "types": ["@twilio-labs/serverless-runtime-types/index.d.ts"],

try to replace like this
"types": ["node_modules/@twilio-labs/serverless-runtime-types/index.d.ts"]

let me if you still have issue

Comment: Adding the `node_modules/` prefix actually was causing an error in the tsconfig.json file. It's fine as it is now.

Comment: If this is helpful, could you please mark it as a useful answer? It will be beneficial for others as well. Thank you!